# jQuery + HTML - Dos valores en un mismo input?

Tags: jquery

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema..

Tengo un Input con Opciones el cual identifica el precio de un producto.

```
<tr>
    <td width="180">Cantidad de wCoins:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="precio" id="creditos">
    <option value="100">100 $100 ARS</option>
    <option value="200">200 $200 ARS</option>
    <option value="300">300 $300 ARS</option>
</select> </td>
  </tr>
```

y tengo un Script jQuery para que cuando se modifique este  valor y el campo de cuenta, automaticamente se inserte en un Input Hidden llamado referencia.

> $('#creditos').change(function() {
>       $('#referencia').val($('#cuenta').val()+"-"+$(this).val()); });      $('#cuenta').change(function() {
>       $('#referencia').val($(this).val()+"-"+$('#creditos').val()); });

Hasta ahí va todo bien, ahora, el problema que yo tengo es que en el Input de las opciones el Value indica el precio y yo además necesito indicar la cantidad de esos "wCoins"
Osea, yo en mi Input Hidden "Referencia" necesito indicar la cuenta y la cantidad de wCoins, es posible agregar otro valor más al Input de Options?

Por ejemplo:

```
 <tr>
        <td width="180">Cantidad de wCoins:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="precio" id="creditos">
        <option value="100" value2="100">100 $100 ARS</option>
        <option value="200" value2="200">200 $200 ARS</option>
        <option value="300" value2="300">300 $300 ARS</option>
    </select> </td>
      </tr>
```

Pregunto desde la total ignorancia, disculpen y muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí puedes agregar otro valor atributo al option, solo que este valor no sera enviado por el formulario cuando lo envíes. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un `input[hidden]` que contenga el wCoin. El valor del atributo value2 le sera asignado cuando el `select` cambie:

```js
$("#creditos").change(function(){
   var value2 = $(this).find("option:selected")
                .attr("data-value2");
   $("#wCoin").val(value2);
});

$("#enviar").click(function(){
   console.log($("form").serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="precio" id="creditos">
  <option> -- SELECCIONE UNA OPCION --</option>
          <option value="100" data-value2="100">100 $100 ARS</option>
          <option value="200" data-value2="200">200 $200 ARS</option>
          <option value="300" data-value2="300">300 $300 ARS</option>
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" id="wCoin" name="wCoin" />
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviar" />

</form>
```

Asi el valor se enviara al servidor como `wCoin`.

Comment: Esta respuesta se ve bien, pero cambiaría una cosa: en lugar de usar `value2` usaría un data-atributo para que sea HTML estándar y válido.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Lo pense, pero para no complicarle las cosas al OP decidi no incluirlo. Aun asi lo hare. Gracias por el interes.

Comment: Excelente! Me sirvió y pude lograr el final, que el Valor Input "referencia" enviara el valor "cuenta-wcoins" por ejemplo.
"micuenta-1500"